# Cannot resolve type inference when overloading function extensions

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

Given the following method extensions (JsonResult is just a wrapper with some additional fields):

```
fun <T, R> T.toJson(transform: (T) -> R) = JsonResult(transform(this))

fun <T, R> List<T>.toJson(transform: (T) -> R) = JsonResult(this.map(transform))

fun <T, R> Page<T>.toJson(transform: (T) -> R) = JsonResult(this.content.map(transform)
```

When I try to call any of the above methods, either from a list or an object that is not a list, I get a compiler error with the message `Cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference` which I expect

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page

val person = Person()
person.toJson { } // compiler error

val people = List<Person>()
people.toJson { } // compiler error

val pageablePeople = Page<Person>
pageablePeople.toJson { }
```

I wonder if there is any other (idiomatic?) way to declare those functions without changing their names.

Answer (score 0):

The reason, you're getting overload resolution errors is because a receiver of type `List<T>` matches both, `fun <T, R> T.toJson` and `fun <T, R> List<T>.toJson`.

Extension functions with an unbound receiver can be problematic, because they will appear in every autocompletion suggestion and because they are always candidates in overload resolution.

I would suggest making the unbound version either a top-level function or putting it in an `object`.

Example:

```
fun <T, R> toJson(t: T, transform: (T) -> R) = JsonResult(transform(t))

fun <T, R> List<T>.toJson(transform: (T) -> R) = JsonResult(map(transform))

fun <T, R> Page<T>.toJson(transform: (T) -> R) = JsonResult(content.map(transform))

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val person = Person()
    toJson(person) {}

    val people = listOf<Person>()
    people.toJson { }

    val pageablePeople = Page<Person>()
    pageablePeople.toJson { }
}
```

Additionally, in the case of classes that you have control over, you can make `toJson` an instance function which always wins agains extension functions in overload resolution.

```
class Page<T>(val content: List<T>) {
    fun <R> toJson(transform: (T) -> R) = JsonResult(content.map(transform))
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kirill for taking the time to respond. I'm aware of the inability of the compiler to resolve the type but I wish I could say T where T is direct child of Any and not a Collection or any other type.
I like the workaround of passing the unbound object as argument though.
As a side note, I have no control over some of the classes.

Comment: The only issue I see with `fun <T, R> toJson(t: T, transform: (T) -> R) = JsonResult(transform(t))` is that is not consistent with the other extensions and callees should remember to call toJson(obj)

Comment: I understand your concerns. The only alternative is renaming one of the overloads.